# Unable to Access https

Tags: ssl

I'm using ubuntu 10.04. Few days back I installed some files from update manager and restarted my system. Now I'm not able to access any of **https** sites and in all browsers I face the same problem. Can any one help me out.

```
Installed the following packages:

icedtea6-plugin (6b18-1.8.1-0ubuntu1)
libaccess-bridge-java (1.26.2-3)
libaccess-bridge-java-jni (1.26.2-3)
openjdk-6-jre (6b18-1.8.1-0ubuntu1)


Upgraded the following packages:

firefox (3.6.11+build3+nobinonly-0ubuntu0.10.04.1) to 3.6.12+build1+nobinonly-0ubuntu0.10.04.1
firefox-branding (3.6.11+build3+nobinonly-0ubuntu0.10.04.1) to 3.6.12+build1+nobinonly-0ubuntu0.10.04.1
firefox-gnome-support (3.6.11+build3+nobinonly-0ubuntu0.10.04.1) to 3.6.12+build1+nobinonly-0ubuntu0.10.04.1
e2fslibs (1.41.11-1ubuntu2) to 1.41.11-1ubuntu2.1
e2fsprogs (1.41.11-1ubuntu2) to 1.41.11-1ubuntu2.1
libc-bin (2.11.1-0ubuntu7.4) to 2.11.1-0ubuntu7.5
libc-dev-bin (2.11.1-0ubuntu7.4) to 2.11.1-0ubuntu7.5
libc6 (2.11.1-0ubuntu7.4) to 2.11.1-0ubuntu7.5
libc6-dev (2.11.1-0ubuntu7.4) to 2.11.1-0ubuntu7.5
libc6-i686 (2.11.1-0ubuntu7.4) to 2.11.1-0ubuntu7.5
libcomerr2 (1.41.11-1ubuntu2) to 1.41.11-1ubuntu2.1
libss2 (1.41.11-1ubuntu2) to 1.41.11-1ubuntu2.1
python-papyon (0.4.8-0ubuntu1) to 0.4.8-0ubuntu2
ttf-symbol-replacement (1.1.42-0ubuntu4) to 1.2-0ubuntu6~lucid5
update-manager (1:0.134.10) to 1:0.134.11
update-manager-core (1:0.134.10) to 1:0.134.11
update-manager-kde (1:0.134.10) to 1:0.134.11
wine (1.1.42-0ubuntu4) to 1.2-0ubuntu6~lucid5
wine1.2 (1.1.42-0ubuntu4) to 1.2-0ubuntu6~lucid5
firefox (3.6.10+build1+nobinonly-0ubuntu0.10.04.1) to 3.6.11+build3+nobinonly-0ubuntu0.10.04.1
firefox-branding (3.6.10+build1+nobinonly-0ubuntu0.10.04.1) to 3.6.11+build3+nobinonly-0ubuntu0.10.04.1
firefox-gnome-support (3.6.10+build1+nobinonly-0ubuntu0.10.04.1) to 3.6.11+build3+nobinonly-0ubuntu0.10.04.1
libnspr4-0d (4.8.4-0ubuntu1) to 4.8.6-0ubuntu0.10.04.2
libnss3-1d (3.12.6-0ubuntu3) to 3.12.8-0ubuntu0.10.04.1
thunderbird (3.0.8+build2+nobinonly-0ubuntu0.10.04.1) to 3.0.9+build1+nobinonly-0ubuntu0.10.04.1
xulrunner-1.9.2 (1.9.2.10+build1+nobinonly-0ubuntu0.10.04.1) to 1.9.2.11+build3+nobinonly-0ubuntu0.10.04.1
```

I think problem with this **libnss3-1d** may be.

Comment: open synaptic from your system>administration menu, go to file>history and tell us what was last updated. It might be a bug.

Comment: Did you try with a browser that does *not* use `libnss3`?  (For example Midori).

Comment: woking fine in midori. how do I downgrade libnss3

Comment: Could you please elaborate on the problem ? What is happening when you try to access some https site ?

Comment: What error do you get when accessing https sites?

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If this is still a problem you could do the following.

1.) Re-install libnss3-1d

or

2.) Downgrade to a previous version

The easiest way to do either of these is using Synapic Package Manager.

**To Re-install**

1. Load Synaptic Package Manager.
2. search for libnss3-1d
3. right-click on the package and select "Mark for re-installation".
4. Press the apply button.
5. Test to see if it worked.

**To downgrade - not recommended as you may then miss some security fixes**

1. Load Synaptic Package Manager.
2. search for libnss3-1d
3. click the package menu and select "Force version".
4. select the version you require and click "Force version".
5. Press the apply button.
6. Test to see if it worked.

Thanks
Chris

Comment: still getting getting same error page for https sites.

Answer (score 0):

Also, double check that nothing's changed recently in your firewall settings (on ubuntu if you have ufw installed), or (unrelated to your update manager changes) your router firewall.